# How do I integrate Devise and Facebook's registration social plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I want to implement Facebook's [Registration plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

How do I do it using Devise ? is there any Devise/OmniAuth extension available ?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using devise 1.2, the documentation is there in devise's github

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: I followed that guide. but I want to implement the registration plugin I linked to. not facebook connect

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the registration plugin. It's aimed for web users that don't yet have a Facebook account. If you want to use that, then add it as a simple iframe with a callback returning them to you site, and then add a regular Omniauth Facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a gem [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery)